# Filtering in lm() with several variables

Tags: r, filter, subset, lm

I'm working through a spreadsheet and would like to create a linear model that considers how several variables affect R&D expenditure. One of the variables (called CEO), notes wether a CEO has a PhD or not. This is identifiable in the data as CEO = 1 (has a PhD), CEO = 0 (doesn't have a PhD). When I write my code for the linear model with just CEO it takes in both, which makes it difficult to interpret how each have an effect on R&D expenditure individually.

```
#This is my initial code:
reg3 <- lm(RD.exp ~ NETincome*Assets..total.*CEO, 
             data = data1,
             na.action=na.omit)
```

I would like to filter it so that I can run the same regression but where only CEO = 1 is considered.
I've tried filtering it through dplyr but it didn't work. I also tried this line of code:

```
CEO1 <- data3[which(data3$CEO==1),]
```

but this made the data turn into chr again and when I try to use as.numeric it won't turn it back to num.

Then the idea would be for the code to look like this:

```
reg3 <- lm(RD.exp ~ NETincome*Assets..total.*CEO1, 
             data = data1,
             na.action=na.omit)
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this!

Thank you

Comment: Hi, please show us the output from dput(head(data1, 5)).  What do you mean when you say "dplyr but it didn't work"?

Comment: `lm(..., data=..., subset= CEO==1)`

Comment: or `lm(..., data=..., subset= CEO=="1")` if $CEO is *character*.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comments, three possible ways to go, all will yield the same results assuming all three of your variables are numeric.  For all three you likely want to drop `CEO` from the formula since it will be a constant and produce interaction `NA`s.

Using `subset` inside `lm`

```r
one <- lm(RD.exp ~ NETincome * Assets..total., 
   data = data1, 
   subset = CEO == 1, 
   na.action = na.omit)
```

Using `dplyr::filter`

```r
library(dplyr)

two <- data1 %>% 
   dplyr::filter(CEO == 1) %>% 
   lm(RD.exp ~ NETincome * Assets..total., 
      data = ., 
      na.action = na.omit)
```

using base `r` (don't use `which`)

```r
three <- lm(RD.exp ~ NETincome * Assets..total., 
   data = data1[data1$CEO == 1,], 
   na.action = na.omit)
```

Produces identical coefficients for all three

```r
all.equal(one$coefficients, two$coefficients, three$coefficients)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Data hopefully like yours

```r
set.seed(2020)
data1 <- data.frame(
   RD.exp = sample(10000:20000, 100, replace = TRUE),
   NETincome = sample(50000:90000, 100, replace = TRUE),
   Assets..total. = sample(100000:900000, 100, replace = TRUE),
   CEO = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```